# How to install directx-9 in desktop converted app

Tags: uwp, directx-9, desktop-bridge

I have created a UWP app for Windows 10 using the Desktop Bridge. My app need Directx-9, how to install automatically Directx-9 when installing my app. Any one knows?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 already includes DirectX 12, DirectX 11.x, DirectX 10.x, and DirectX 9.0c. The "DirectX End-User Runtimes" does *absolutely nothing* to change or install the DirectX Runtime on Windows XP Service Pack 2 or Service Pack 3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.x, or Windows 10.

The *only* thing the "DirectX End-User Runtimes" installs is the various optional side-by-side components: D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, XAudio 2.7, XInput 1.3, and XACT.  If your application makes use of one of those, then you need to use the "DirectX End-User Runtimes" to deploy them, but you can trim down the CABs to just a few of them.

See [Not So Direct Setup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/)

For details on the Desktop Bridge, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  "D3DX9_43.dll" is what I need, it is not included in Windows 10, and it cannot work by copying it into my package. My converted app is packaged by visual studio 2017, do you know how to make my app work, and how to use the "DirectX End-User Runtimes" to deploy ?